# "one day" vs "one-day"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I wrote the following sentence in Microsoft Word:

> I was destined to one day live in the corridors of the Great Library and digest the world.

And Word wanted me to change "one day" to "one-day".

Any thoughts on this? I couldn't find this precise question on here, appreciate any help.

Comment: As a piece of general advice, Word— like any other machine spellchecker or grammar-checker— doesn't understand what you intend to communicate, it only detects certain patterns, or deviations therefrom. Take its spelling and punctuation advice with a pinch of salt, and its grammar advice with a heaping tablespoon.

Comment: If "one day" is to be used as an adjective, as in "one-day sale", then the hyphen should be used.  But that's not the way you're using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event that occurs for only a day is hyphenated: We're having a one-day sale on televisions.

An event that (one desires) occurs in the future is not: He will one day be King.

Therefore, your example should not be hyphenated.  I guess Word was just trying to draw your attention to the possible alternative.  Word isn't good at detecting context.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphenated form of the phrase is used whenever an adjective is required. "The band played a one-day gig in Miami Beach."

Otherwise, the unhyphenated phrase can be used howsoever one would use an adjective-and-noun combination. As a phrase used as an adverb: "The band played in Miami Beach one day." As an adjective-and-noun: "The length of the band's gig in Miami Beach was one day."

Also, since you are the author of the sentence, I would not put the phrase in the middle of an infinitive.